How to decrypt a payload where 'cipher' => 'AES-256-CBC?
I have configured a webhook on an external system,  the payload I'm receiving is :
{action=updated, data=eyJpdiI6ImJLeURnZklsMFcrdWpEMjYrZzFkMGc9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiZy9lM3lXZkNBaHA0MFVwVlFDT3BUSVpIaWxrbTBLS213cGtVazQwU2dYTGZsc0s1eXpXMGhpbXYwUTdqSkRTc2ZQTXdrUlZvS1ZTU0piNlpybUN0eGxDRHcwUHh4Nkw0aklsUEhWSFdQcXYyRTl5RTZzNm9VRDgwNjFONExneGoiLCJtYWMiOiJmNTkwNzRhNTk3MTc0NTY1OGYwNWNjYjA0YWJjODAyZjVmNTYzYjExZDljY2JjOTI3NjBlZGZkZjc3NGRkNzEyIiwidGFnIjoiIn0=, id=7657, table=demographics}
and the secret key on the webhook UI is : WCPDMPxUon4u5kwZrw1LKG3oak4av64mlfEt4mgeF5w=
I believe the data field is encrypted.
After messaging the developer of the external system that is sending the payload, all they can tell me is this:

*Our developer team has confirmed that Open SSL is used to encrypt and decrypt the webhook requests. They've also mentioned that there's a second layer using the cipher algorithm:
'cipher' => 'AES-256-CBC',
I hope this information is helpful to you.*

I have tried to decrypt this but keep getting errors related to the key not being the correct size.
What are the steps to decrypt this payload?
I tried decrypting and got errors saying the secret key was not the right size

Base64 decode data, then you get a JSON string with IV, actual ciphertext and MAC. Test your decryption code with this data. If you get stuck, post your code and describe the problem.

after Base64 decoding data, i get {"iv":"bKyDgfIl0W+ujD26+g1d0g==","value":"g/e3yWfCAhp40UpVQCOpTIZHilkm0KKmwpkUk40SgXLflsK5yzW0himv0Q7jJDSsfPMwkRVoKVSSJb6ZrmCtxlCDw0Pxx6L4jIlPHVHWPqv2E9yE6s6oUD8061N4Lgxj","mac":"f59074a5971745658f05ccb04abc802f5f563b11d9ccbc92760edfdf774dd712","tag":""} , which i then try to decrypt using decrypt , passing in "value" as the 'AES Encrypted text' and "iv" into Enter 'IV Used During Encryption' , 256 key size and WCPDMPxUon4u5kwZrw1LKG3oak4av64mlfEt4mgeF5w= as the secret key, and get an error

Length of secret key should be 32 for 256 bits key size

WCPD... is the Base64 encoded key. The raw (= Base64 decoded) key is 32 bytes in size. Note that IV and value (= the actual ciphertext) are also Base64 encoded. The MAC is hex encoded.

The website you are using is not suitable for the decryption of your data, as the encoding can only be set to a limited extent. If you still want to work with online tools, try e.g. CyberChef. But note that your post is then probably off topic. SO is more for programming related problems (where a code is provided).

how do i get the raw Base64 decoded value for the secret key? using the same method I did for data on the secret key, resulted in random characters and not letters/numbers. Is this an issue with the system giving the wrong key?

https://gchq.github.io/CyberChef/#recipe=From_Base64('A-Za-z0-9%2B/%3D',true,false)AES_Decrypt(%7B'option':'Base64','string':'WCPDMPxUon4u5kwZrw1LKG3oak4av64mlfEt4mgeF5w%3D'%7D,%7B'option':'Base64','string':'bKyDgfIl0W%2BujD26%2Bg1d0g%3D%3D'%7D,'CBC','Raw','Raw',%7B'option':'Hex','string':''%7D,%7B'option':'Hex','string':''%7D)&input=Zy9lM3lXZkNBaHA0MFVwVlFDT3BUSVpIaWxrbTBLS213cGtVazQwU2dYTGZsc0s1eXpXMGhpbXYwUTdqSkRTc2ZQTXdrUlZvS1ZTU0piNlpybUN0eGxDRHcwUHh4Nkw0aklsUEhWSFdQcXYyRTl5RTZzNm9VRDgwNjFONExneGo
